# How can I make a correct answer counter in Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 questions and correct answer is 1. How can I make correct answer counter, that will show the user that he answered 2 questions correctly if answered them correctly?

```
print('what is 2+2?')
q1 = input('1)4 , 2)3 , 3)6: ')
print('what is 4-1?')
q2 = input('1)3, 2)4, 3)1: ')
```

Comment: Create a `counter` variable at the top of the program, and increment it whenever the answer is correct.

Comment: like this ?  correct = answer +1    but what else to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable to keep track of the number of correct answers and you need to parse the input to see if the answer was correct. Then you need to print a formatted string to display the number of answers the user got correct. So something like:

```
counter = 0
print('what is 2+2?')
# Ask and check first question
q1 = input('1)4 , 2)3 , 3)6: ')
if int(q1) == 1:
    counter += 1
print('what is 4-1?')
# Ask and check second question
q2 = input('1)3, 2)4, 3)1: ')
if int(q2) == 1:
    counter += 1
print('You got {correct}/2 answers correct!'.format(correct=counter))
```

Comment: @GovnarbBeginner no problem! Please mark as the answer if this works!

Comment: Yes 3mins to wait. thx a lot no more headache!

Comment: if you get the first question wrong and the second question right, it will say you got 2 correct answers. Don't hardcode counter values, increment them. counter += 1

Comment: Good point, fixed the code thanks for catching that @hamsolo474-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the problem

Lets walk through it.
If you are going to ask a long list of questions, and you already know the answers to these questions, instead of writing each question in its own print statement, we should store it a better datatype.
I'm using a dictionary because it can store a question and an answer as a key-value pair.

Then I create a list to store Correct or Incorrect, True or False for each answer. I use a list comprehension here. For each question in qa, make a place for the answer and save it as False.

Now instead of calling multiple print statements we are going to loop over our qa dictionary. This is the advantage of using datatypes well, as this code stays the same size no matter how many questions there are on your quiz, these few lines will run 1 question or a million questions.

enumerate keeps count of what question we are asking, and it starts counting at zero so the first question is question 0.
We are going to loop over qa storing the question number in index and the question itself in key.
Then I create your correct answer counter.
So we look through the list we created earlier called correct, and we count the number of right answers (True values), by using the count method of the list datatype. and we get the current question number, which as mentioned before is stored in index. then '/'.join simply joins the count of correct answers to the questions asked with a / in the middle, so it looks like 1/2 for one right answer out of two questions. Neither of these values are strings, so we convert them to strings using the str function.

Now lets design our question string
Based on what you posted I think you want "counter/questions asked    Question?"
We want to use the same code for each question, but we want the questions to all be unique. So we have to design a template and fill them in during the loop. For this we use the string datatype method called format. Format takes a list of arguments and puts them into a string for you, you should read about it in the python docs. \t is a Tab Character, so our template is "correctAnswers/questionsAskedTABQuestion "

Now lets finally ask the question, so we use input to print our question and receive the response just like you did in your code, however, as input returns a string we can run a string method on it. "".strip() removes leading and trailing whitespace, this is useful because "4", " 4", " 4 ", "4 " are all considered different in the mind of the computer, but by running strip, they all become "4". When using "".strip we need to be careful that there is no leading or trailing whitespace in our list of answers.

And last of all we check to see if the answer is correct, so in our correct list we do a truth test, if the answer given is the same as the answer we have for this question in qa then we set the value of the element in correct to True, otherwise we set it to False.

```
qa = {"What is 2+2?":"4", "What is 4-1?":"3"}
correct = [None for i in qa]
                         
for index, key in enumerate(qa):
  displayCount = '/'.join([str(correct.count(True)), str(index)])
  question = "{0}\t{1} ".format(displayCount, key)
  answer = input(question).strip()
  correct[index] = answer==qa[key]
```

The python docs are absolutely excellent, I very highly recommend you read more about datatypes, looping, logical tests as well as anything you didnt understand about my code.